# Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets was not found while opening projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, windows-ce

I tried to create a smart device project in Visual Studio 2008.

Target Platform: **Windows Mobile 5.0 Pocket PC SDK**.

.NET Compact Framework version: **.NET Compact Framework 3.5**

But I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600010&referringTitle=KB you need to install both the framework and power toys to have it compiled.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is poorly documented.

Both .NET Compact Framework Redistributable and Power Toys must be installed for all necessary files (such as MSBuild targets files) to be available for compilation.

Comment: Basically this got nuked in Windows 10 Anniversary update, but if you re-install the Power Toys again it fixes it. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

Comment: Power Toys fix my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @KendallBennett After the latest Windows update a few minutes ago, your link saved my bacon. Much appreciated!

Comment: @ Suncat2000 we thankfully ported all our code to Android so finally got rid of Compact Framework, but glad it helped! It took years to finally get that done on our end.

Comment: The file you're looking for is "NETCFv35PowerToys.msi". Above link no longer works but is currently available here: https://web.archive.org/web/20080726091821/https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/a/c/fac1342d-044d-4d88-ae97-d278ef697064/NETCFv35PowerToys.msi

Comment: Matt - Thanks! You are a lifesaver. Google was failing me big time.

Comment: For archived compact framework 3.5 you can use https://web.archive.org/web/20200811074848/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=65

Answer (score 40):

For all those who end up here as a result of the Windows 10 "anniversary update" note that the file Microsoft.Compactframework.CSharp.Targets can be found in the C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5 directory and copied back to where it belongs!

(Same with Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets, Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.targets)

Comment: I had already nuked that directory when I ran into this after Anniversary handily decided to install itself. Doh! But I quickly discovered I could recover it by reinstalling the power toys. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

Comment: To me it happened on Creators Update. Reinstalling .NET Compact Framework Redistributable and Power Toys as in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36385715/2614479 did the trick.

Comment: "April Update" does the same.

Comment: I can't find Windows.old folder, finally copy from my coworker's pc, then it works.

Answer (score 10):

It also happened to me, and more than just once, with two projects for Visual Studio 2008 Professional.

It's quite easy for me to solve this problem: just re-install (I use the "Repair" option that seems to work great) the **Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5**. You can find this tool here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13442

I think that sometimes, maybe after some Windows/.NET framework automatic updates, this problem can still occur. But the solution is quite easy in this case, and there is no need to edit the .vbproj/.csproj file!

Comment: Indeed, the "Repair" option is enough. - I am considering to try my future builds with a docker: https://gist.github.com/ashalkhakov/cc2bc798caecb52ed123f9a8ed0e575d

Answer (score 2):

I met the same mistake . Solution vs2008 repair.

Answer (score 1):

For people landing here via a Google search and using Jetbrains Ryder:

I'm using both VS2008 and Jetbrains Ryder next to each other for development. My VS2008 was working fine whilst Ryder was not. I had to manually copy a few files from one folder to another to make it work.

To fix it you'll have to copy a few *targets* files from one folder to another.

Go to the folder **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5** and copy the following files:

- Microsoft.CompactFramework.Common.targets
- Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets
- Microsoft.CompactFramework.VisualBasic.targets

Now go to **C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin** and paste the copied files here.

Finally, restart Ryder and you're good to go!

The above steps did the trick for me for the Ryder IDE but if you're having the same troubles with VS2008 it might be worth a shot as well.

Answer (score 0):

Open your csproj file in notepad and Find the below line:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

and change it into

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: Can not find csproj file.  from the error, it seems that the csproj file is somewhere in temp folder

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
Old line:

```
> <Import
> Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets"
> />
```

change into:

```
>  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).